# Best practice for draggable, sortable with paging records

Tags: user-behavior, grid, pagination, drag-n-drop, sort

What will be best design practice for having items thumbnail with option as drag gable, sort able with paging records(considering more than 1000+ records)?

Below is just my current implementation.

Now I want each box to drag and sort order.

I was thinking about JQuery Sortable with grid type drag and sort.

But is there any better way to get all these with best user experience?

[image]

Comment: If draggable and with paging, the UX is going to be very awkward, as you'll really only be able to drag within a page. Dragging to next/previous page will be hard to implement, unless you have "hover areas" on left and right to get it to page up/down. Maybe scrolling canvas is better than paged, cf. dragging files within Windows Explorer, etc?

Comment: What is the domain, and what tasks are the user trying to do? Is this primarily viewing? why are they dragging? Why is pagination needed?

Comment: @MikeM It's backend system, where admin will be set items display order. Pagination is not primary goal. Without pagination what can be best UX ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Try allowing multiselection, drag and drop plus a contextual menu for repositioning 1 or more items.

Allow `Shift` + select for multiple items (or single click for one item). Then, the **Right click** or **Contextual** menu can serve up bulk actions (if multiple are selected). They can still reposition selected items by traditional drag and drop, in addition to an explicit popup menu.

**NOTE:** 'Move' may not be the right term for your app, since they're not changing the location, but repositioning; perhaps you can test with users to see what best conveys the concept.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh5YLm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Google drive allows similar actions: here's a pic of their grid view, with multiselect:

[image]

**This model allows:**

- 1 click for single selection
- Shift click for multiple
- Contextual actions for the selected items

As for pagination, I don't see what the advantage is in your application. Is it simply an implementation detail, because returning large amounts of results is an expensive API call?

If so, maybe have a 'Load more' button.